Eligibility for French Citizenship as the Child of a French Parent, Born Abroad. Father dead before birth
I am the son of a French father and a Mexican mother. My father died in an accident before I was born.
I was born in Mexico, and I would like to know if I have the possibility to acquire French citizenship, even though I was not born in France.

Technically, you're not really asking the right question. You are most likely already a French citizen but if you aren't, there is no special procedure to become one. You can of course move to France and eventually naturalize (at least in principle) but I assume your goal is to find something easier and quicker.
So the question becomes:

Were you born French? The children of a French citizen are French citizens, being born abroad doesn't make a difference per se. The main issue in your case is that your father died before your birth. Were your parents married? Is your relationship to your father legally established (e.g. through your birth certificate)?
Can you still use your French citizenship? There is a somewhat convoluted rule that causes French citizenship to lapse for people who live abroad and do not maintain official ties with France. We have several Q&A about that but none addressing your situation. In your case, the first issue is whether your father lived in France or moved to Mexico (or elsewhere) before the accident that killed him? And are you older than 50? If the answer is yes to both questions, you cannot use your French citizenship anymore. If the answer is no to either question, you are very likely to be a French citizen to this day.

